# An elliptical curve over GF(2^3) is defined as y^2+xy=x^3+ax^2+b with the given value of a= g^3 and b=1.R = P + Q, where P = (0, 1) and Q = (g^2, 1)

Tags: elliptic-curves

An elliptical curve over $GF(2^3)$ is defined as $y^2+xy=x^3+ax^2+b$ with the given value of $a= g^3$ and $b=1$. $R = P + Q$, where $P = (0, 1)$ and $Q = (g^2, 1)$

Can someone solve this question using an elliptical curve cryptosystem? I have tried solving it but could not do it.
I need to find R.

[image: Formulas Used]

[image: GF Table]

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. What did you try? Hint: how many values $a$ and $b$ can take?

Comment: I have the answer but i am unable to understand how it came. Saw it in a textbook.

Answer: We have λ = 0 and R = (g^5, g^4).

Comment: this is just a calculation of the point addition with symbolic computation. Show your steps in your question so that we can help you. Answer is not work!

Comment: @mazino: this exercise starts with a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) with $2^3$ elements and some generator $g$. It's then defined an Elliptic Curve group formed by the $(x,y)$ with $x$ and $y$ in the field and matching the equation, plus another element for the neutral. You are asked to apply [that group's addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law). There's nothing elliptical involved. One difficulty is that the equation is not in the most usual form, hence you need to change that form, or use an appropriate addition formula.

Comment: I got my answer. I used the formulas above. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: could you write your answer and close this question?

Answer (score -1):

[image: Answer]

[image: Formula Used]

[image: Formula Used]

I used these calculated values to solve the above question

Comment: We have $\LaTeX$/MathJax enabled on our site. And the answer should include the steps.